# FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter is incompatible with CompositeFileListFilter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am watching several remote folders using the `int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter` but am having trouble with the local-filters.

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundChannelPmse"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            channel="chan"
            remote-directory="${rdir1}"
            filter="remoteUnseenFilter"
            preserve-timestamp="true"
            local-directory="${ldir1}"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
            local-filter="localOnlyXmlFilter"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            local-filename-generator-expression="#this.toLowerCase()"
            >
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="-1" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundChannelOfcomDefault"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            channel="chan"
            remote-directory="${rdir2}"
            filter="remoteUnseenFilter"
            preserve-timestamp="true"
            local-directory="${ldir2}"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
            local-filter="localOnlyCsvFilter"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            local-filename-generator-expression="#this.toLowerCase()"
            >
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="-1" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Each filter is a composite filter which includes a FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter and another, such as IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter and/or my ExtensionFileListFilter e.g.

```
<bean id="localOnlyXmlFilter"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter" />
            <bean
                class="uk.co.bigsoft.app.imports.filters.ExtensionFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg value="xml" />
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="uk.co.bigsoft.app.imports.filters.PrefixFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="pref2_" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="localFileStore" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" name="prefix" value="" />
                <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="localOnlyCsvFilter"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter" />
            <bean
                class="uk.co.bigsoft.app.imports.filters.ExtensionFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg value="csv" />
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="uk.co.bigsoft.app.imports.filters.PrefixFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="pref1_" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="localFileStore" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" name="prefix" value="" />
                <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The file downloads ok but depending on whether localOnlyXmlFilter or localOnlyCsvFilter runs first, the one that runs second won't see it because it has already been remembered by the one that ran first! I suppose what I really want is for the local filter to make its way down the filter list and *stop* when the filter is false (or returns no entries) instead of running all the filters anyway (which seems a bit pointless to me).

Is there anything that will do this? I've been looking at reorganising the filters but I keep running into problems.

```
public class StoppingCompositeFileFilter extends AbstractFileListFilter<File> {

    private List<AbstractFileListFilter<File>> filters;

    public StoppingCompositeFileFilter(List<AbstractFileListFilter<File>> filters) {
    this.filters = filters;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean accept(File file) {
    for (AbstractFileListFilter<File> filter : filters) {
       -->      // Fails to compile because accept() is abstract for AbstractFileListFilter
        if (!filter.accept(file)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

    }
}
```

or this one which seems overly complicated:

```
class AnotherFilter implements FileListFilter<File> {

    private List<FileListFilter<File>> filters;


    @Override
    public List<File> filterFiles(File[] files) {
        List<File> keeping = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (File file : files) {
            for (FileListFilter<File> filter : filters) {
                keeping = filter.filterFiles(keeping.toArray(new File[keeping.size()]));
                if (keeping.size() == 0) {
                    return new ArrayList<File>();
                }
            }
        }
        return keeping;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CompositeFileListFilter` logic looks like:

```
public List<F> filterFiles(F[] files) {
    Assert.notNull(files, "'files' should not be null");
    List<F> results = new ArrayList<F>(Arrays.asList(files));
    for (FileListFilter<F> fileFilter : this.fileFilters) {
        List<F> currentResults = fileFilter.filterFiles(files);
        results.retainAll(currentResults);
    }
    return results;
}
```

So, I think you should build your own logic based on the existing algorithm, rather then invent a new design which may be wrong or enough complicated.

Not sure yet what you'd like to reach, but in my opinion the `AcceptOnce` must be first in the list...

Comment: The `AcceptOnce` has to go at the end because if it is at the beginning and one of the other later conditions fails then no one will be able to process it. The current system seems to work by applying the condition to all the files and keeping the ones that are still valid. Each condition is applied in full before the next one. However I'd like the opposite, to run each condition against each file. It's a subtle difference, but I can't find a way to do it which allows me to use all the existing filters. I suspect that my integration design is wrong so that's the bit I really need help with.